# CSS overflow is not working

Tags: html, css

I have panel and I am just displaying some html list elements inside it. I have put `overflow:auto;` for main `<ul>` but if `<li>` data contains some long long text then it is getting displayed in next line.

Can it is possible to wrap in the same line with horizontal scroll bar in main panel. I want the data should be in single line.

Link to JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skumary2k/7wj7mje2/

**HTML code:**

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden; position:absolute; top:0px; height:350px; width:870px;"
     role="group" class="k-pane k-scrollable">
  <div class="miller-column-wrap">
    <div class="miller-column-inner-wrap">
      <div id="millersColID" tabindex="0" class="miller">
        <div class="columns">
          <ul style="top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <li>This is some really very long long long data which I need to show here... #1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```css
.miller
{
    font-family:  Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #282828;
/*  margin-bottom: 20px; */
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
/*  background: #f5f5f5; */
    outline: 0;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.miller div.columns
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 275px;
    left: 0;
    top: 20px;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.miller div.columns ul
{
    box-shadow: #aaa 4px 0 8px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-right: solid 1px #ddd;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 325px;
    height: 275px;
}

.miller li
{
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    list-style-type: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    width: 325px;

}
```

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: Correct. The overflow property does not control how the content is formatted, or whether there's overflow or not.

Comment: @sdcr: Thanks it is working. Can you post this as answer so that, I can mark it as right answer.